# Convert UL list to radial / circle list

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I'm trying to transform an infographic image into something editable in HTML / JS / CSS.

I would like to do as close as the example image. I need it to be flexible enough not to need to pass CSS coordinates of each item, so that it is editable via admin (add / remove).

[image]

As close as I could get, I was using TweenMax in an example I got on the web. But I'm stuck. My biggest question is how to position the text according to the area where it is (if the circle is to the right, align the title to the right, if it is to the left, do the same aligning to the left).

```js
function radiallist(trgt) {
        var itemAmount = $(trgt).find('.radiallist-item').length;
        var angle = 0,
          currItem;
        var itemStartDist = trgt.width() * 2;
      for (i = 0; i < itemAmount; i++) {
       currItem = $(trgt).find('.radiallist-item:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
       angle = (Math.PI * 2 / itemAmount) * i;
       x = itemStartDist * Math.cos(angle) - (currItem.width() / 2);
       y = itemStartDist * Math.sin(angle) - (currItem.height() / 2);
       TweenMax.to(currItem, 0, {
        x: x,
        y: y
       });
      }
        radiallistItemPos($('.radiallist'));
     }
     radiallist($('.radiallist'));

     function radiallistItemPos(trgt) {
      var itemAmount = $(trgt).find('.radiallist-item').length;
      var angle = 0,
      currItem;
      var itemEndDist = 100 * itemAmount/8;
      for (i = 0; i < itemAmount; i++) {
       currItem = $(trgt).find('.radiallist-item:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
       angle = (Math.PI * 2 / itemAmount) * i;
       x = itemEndDist * Math.cos(angle) - (currItem.width() / 2);
       y = itemEndDist * Math.sin(angle) - (currItem.height() / 2);
       TweenMax.to(currItem, 2, {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        alpha: 1
       });
      }
     }
```

```css
.radiallist {
      position:absolute;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      overflow:hidden;
     }
     .radiallist .radiallist-btn {
      position:relative;
      height:330px;
      width:330px;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      margin-top:-165px;
      margin-left:-165px;
      z-index:2;
      text-align:center;
      border:3px dotted #CCC;
      border-radius:165px;
     }
     .radiallist .radiallist-btn img {
      position:absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      margin-left:-107px;
      margin-top:-31px;
     }
     .radiallist .radiallist-items {
      position:absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin:0;
      list-style-type:none;
      padding:0;
     }
     .radiallist .radiallist-item {
      position:absolute;
      background:url(https://i.imgur.com/LMgR3Pe.png) no-repeat center;
      z-index:1;
      text-align:right;
      font-family:'Din';
      font-size:14px;
      color:#777;
      font-weight:bold;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      white-space:nowrap;
     }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <section id="conteudo">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="radiallist">
       <div class="radiallist-btn"></div>
       <ul class="radiallist-items">
        <li class="radiallist-item">Televisões</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Telas Touch</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Notebooks</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Tablets</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Impressoras</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Estruturas Box Truss</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Backdrops</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Palcos</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Caixas de som</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Microfones</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Iluminação</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Filmadoras</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Máquinas fotográficas</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Climatizadores</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Rádios</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Totens Carregadores</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Tendas</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Geradores de Energia</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Vídeo-games</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Equipamentos para transmissão</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Unifilas</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Pulpitos</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Máquinas de neve</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Máquinas de fumaça</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Máquinas de gelo seco</li>
        <li class="radiallist-item">Projetores</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
```

Can anyone give me some light on this?

Comment: After a (very) brief glance, IMO you've shot yourself in the foot by using (abusing really) `<li>` as the only structure in a complexly structured view. At a minimum you should consider using `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to wrap the `<li>`s - but more structure facilitates more control.

Comment: @RandyCasburn feel free to suggest a new structure. I did it this way to make it more flexible, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing for which [D3](https://github.com/d3/d3) is suited.